# Build Firefox on Android

Tags: android, firefox, fennec

Trying to build Firefox on Android by referring to this page.
[Simple Firefox for Android build](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Simple_Firefox_for_Android_build)

However, the build command *./mach build* fails with the error

```
 ERROR: Could not find autoconf 2.13
```

However autoconf is already installed on the system.

```
$ autoconf --version
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+/Autoconf: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>, <http://gnu.org/licenses/exceptions.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David J. MacKenzie and Akim Demaille.
```

Here's the pastebin of the [error.](http://pastebin.com/8q2uFtvK)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 16.04 VM, had autoconf 2.69 installed. However, to successfully build Firefox for Android autoconf 2.13 is required.

Resolved it using the following :

```
$ sudo apt-get remove autoconf
$ sudo apt-get install autoconf2.13
```